# Clicking on a link in html doesn't reroute me to the correct page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, function, routes

For the last 2 weeks, I have been trying to get this to work but I can't seem to find the problem. when I click on a user to chat with it doesn't seem to create a chat room between the two. I have followed that tutorial https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-aspnet/ but edited a few things like my database. After debugging it seems like it doesn't do anything when I click on one of the user links.

I have tried renaming everything and starting all over again multiple times.

I think it might have something to do with the routeconfig or that it doesnt even call the javascript gae on click.

**all it does is change my current adress: localhost/chat to localhost/chat#**

My View with javascript:

Javascript:

```
 // get chat data
    function getChat(contact_id) {
        $.get("/contact/conversations/" + contact_id)
            .done(function(resp) {
                let chat_data = resp.data || [];
                loadChat(chat_data);
            });
    }

    //load chat data into view
    function loadChat(chat_data) {
        chat_data.forEach(function(data) {
            displayMessage(data);
        });

        $('.chat__body').show();
        $('.__no__chat__').hide();
    }

    // select contact to chat with
    $('.user__item').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        currentContact = {
            id: $(this).data('contact-id'),
            name: $(this).data('contact-name'),
        };
        if (conversationChannelName) {
            pusher.unsubscribe(conversationChannelName);
        }
        conversationChannelName = getConvoChannel((@ViewBag.currentUser.Id * 1), (currentContact.id * 1));
        currentconversationChannel = pusher.subscribe(conversationChannelName);
        bind_client_events();

        $('#contacts').find('li').removeClass('active');
        $('#contacts .contact-' + currentContact.id).find('li').addClass('active');
        getChat(currentContact.id);
    });

    function getConvoChannel(user_id, contact_id) {
        if (user_id > contact_id) {
            return 'private-chat-' + contact_id + '-' + user_id;
        }
        return 'private-chat-' + user_id + '-' + contact_id;
    }
```

html

```html
<div class="__no__chat__">
                                <p>Select a contact to chat with</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body users__body">
                                <ul id="contacts" class="list-group">

                                    @foreach (var user in @ViewBag.allUsers)
                                    {
                                        <a class="user__item contact-@user.Id" href="#" data-contact-id="@user.Id" data-contact-name="@user.FirstName">
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="avatar">
                                                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/no_avatar.png")">
                                                </div>
                                                <span>@user.FirstName</span>
                                                <div class="status-bar"></div>
                                            </li>
                                        </a>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

routeconfig:

```cs
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Login",
                url: "login",
                defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ChatRoom",
                url: "chat",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "GetContactConversations",
                url: "contact/conversations/{contact}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "ConversationWithContact", contact = "" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PusherAuth",
                url: "pusher/auth",
                defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "AuthForChannel" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SendMessage",
                url: "send_message",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "SendMessage" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MessageDelivered",
                url: "message_delivered/{message_id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "MessageDelivered", message_id = "" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this sounds like it's a problem with the JS on page if nothing is happening. Rule that out first.

Have you done any debug output in the JS?

First of all though, can you wrap your click event so it's set up on document ready.

#### Update - also added in `section` code to make sure everything is executed at the right time (i.e. after the bundles for JQuery are loaded)

In your View:

```
@section scripts {
    $(document).ready(function() {
       
        $('.user__item').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            console.log("click registered!");   //also add this directly at the beginning of the click event so you can see if something happens (or not)
            //...your original code below... 
        });
    
    });
}
```

Note: `@section scripts...` should occur only once in your View.

In your `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
    ....
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging but havent been able to make alot of sence out of it. I ususally program C# so dont really know how to debug this. Where would I put the code snippet you provided?

Comment: It's a change in the `Javascript` code you posted above. You're wrapping the `$('.user__item').click` code you have with `$(document).ready(function() { ... }); ` to ensure the page has loaded before the click is bound to your items in the `html` code you sent. In Chrome you can view the console by right clicking on your page then selecting 'inspect'

Comment: After doing this and clicking while checking he console in chrome it didnt show me any output in the console

Comment: I do however get this error ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at http://localhost:51699/chat:238:5

Comment: ah ok - the plot thickens. you don't have jQuery linked up then from the sound of it. In your `Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file you should have a `<link ... />` reference to JQuery? ...or possible a reference like so: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

Comment: Yes! I have the reference @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") and
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

Comment: OK, in `/Scripts` do you have `jquery-xxxx.js` files (where 'xxxx' is the version/minified variation)? Also in `/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` you should have the jquery bundle declared (probably 1st).

Comment: Yes I have a whoe bunch of `jquery-3.3.1` files and have this in my `/scripts` : `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));`

Comment: Ok great. Right, in `_Layout.cshtml` do you have `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` just before the closing `</body>` tag? Add it if not. Then, on your `Javascript` in the OP, wrap it with the edit I'm making in the answer above...

Comment: Ok yes I already had the `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` and do I wrap my entire javascrip in the `@section scripts {`or just that one function

Comment: the entire `<script>...</script>` tags should be wrapped

Comment: Thanks alot!!! Im getting new errors now but thats in the C# code so I can finally start fixing it

Comment: great! glad to be of assistance.